# Define Custom Objects as input & output for Loopback Models

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm a newbie to node.js trying to create a set of APIs with the loopback framework. My requirement is to accept JSON as an input for my API, and I'm trying to define the same in the model JSON file. As per the official documentation, loopback supports the `object` type as an argument type, but I don't see where I can define the JSON object structure. Could someone please let me know how this can be done?
The relevant snippet of the model is as below:

```
"retrieveProfile": {
        "description": "Returns back a particular entity's profile details",
        "isStatic": true,
        "accepts": [
            {
                "arg": "msg",
                "type": "string",
                "http": {
                    "source": "query"
                }
            }
        ],
        "returns": {
            "arg": "greeting",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "http": {
            "verb": "get"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you consider an [embedded model](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Embedded-models-and-relations.html)? That's kind of on a halfway between an object property and a regular related model.

Comment: As far as I can tell, embedded models are part of the `properties` attribute, whereas I'm trying to use the `accepts` attribute. Could you please advise on the best practice in this case?

Comment: @Debojit did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @Jonathan Sadly, no. I had to take the hard way around, as in accept the JSON as a string and `JSON.parse` it afterwards. Works, but not a good implementation, to put it lightly.

Comment: @Debojit I figured it out. I know this is late to the game, but maybe it can help going forward.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks, this does help. It's never late for new info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out. You have the define the custom object as a new model in your loopback instance.

Suppose you have the following two models in your loopback instance (this is psuedo code, haven't tested it, but hopefully you'll get the idea):

`buildings.json`

```
{
  "name": "Buildings",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "rent": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  }
}
```

`tenants.json`

```
{
  "name": "Tenants",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure you declare them in `model-config.json`. If you have these models connected to a datasource, this will still work, but they don't have to be connected to a datasource to make this work. I declared them in `model-config.json` and then set the datasource as `null`.

Then, when you create your remote method, you'd do it like this

`buildings.json`

```
{
  "name": "Buildings",
  ...
  "methods": {
    "chargeRent": {
      "accepts": [
        {
          "arg": "tenant",
          "type": "Tenants",
          "required": true
        }
      ],
      "returns": {
        "root": true,
        "type": "object"
      },
      "http": {
        "verb": "post"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously you can configure your remote method however you want, but the most important part is the `type` you define needs to match the name of the model.

Once you've done this, if you look in the Loopback API explorer at this method, you should see that the documentation shows the custom object as an argument for this endpoint. And, depending on how you've defined the properties for the custom object (i.e. required v. not) it'll throw errors if those properties aren't included.

Hope this helps!